# What does move do for variables that are references?

Tags: rust, closures, move

I have a function that composes multiple functions into a single one:

```rust
fn compose<'a, T>(fns: &'a [&dyn Fn(T) -> T]) -> Box<dyn Fn(T) -> T + 'a> {
    Box::new(move |mut x| {
        for f in fns {
            x = f(x);
        }
        x
    })
}
```

Why do I need to move `fns` here? If I don't put move, I get the following error:

```
error[E0373]: closure may outlive the current function, but it borrows `fns`, which is owned by the current function
 --> src/lib.rs:2:14
  |
2 |     Box::new(|mut x| {
  |              ^^^^^^^ may outlive borrowed value `fns`
3 |         for f in fns {
  |                  --- `fns` is borrowed here
```

I don't get why I need to move the fns into the closure when it's just a reference. What does move actually do here?

Comment: Note that inside the closure, if you don't put `move` then `fns` has type `&&'a […]`. I.e. it's a reference to a reference to a slice. You need `move` to get rid of the outer reference and get the actual `&'a […]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reference is just a normal variable, like any other variable. If you don't `move`, your `fns` inside the closure will be a reference to a reference, which goes out of scope at the end of the function.

Comment: So putting move actually copies the reference? I ask this because, from what I understand, immutable references are copied, right?

Comment: @rencedm112 Yes.